# Validation framework in Spring

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I'm working on spring project, please find the below underline structure.
Employee is bean class, EmployeeReqBean is request class from the url.
MessageHeader is also a bean class and NotNull annotation is added to the same.
From the server I'm sending ajax call and it has POST message like :

```
{
    "messageHeader": {
        "appID": "ABC"
    },
    "filter": {
        "doj": "2015-03-09T05:00:00.000Z",
        "dol": "2015-03-18T05:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

Bean class

```
public class Employee {

    @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
    private String fName;
    @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
    private String doj; /* Date of Joining */
    @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
    private String dol; /* Date of leaving */
    @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
    private int age;

    /*
     * getters & setter for 
    */ 
}

public class EmployeeReqBean {

    @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
    private Employee emp;
    @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
    private MessageHeder header;

    /*
     * getters & setter for 
    */ 
}

public class EmployeeValidator implements Validator {

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

        SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
        EmployeeReqBean employeeReqBean = (EmployeeReqBean)target;
        try {
        String doj = sdf.format(sf.parse(employeeReqBean.getEmployee().getDoj()));
        String  dol = sdf.format(sf.parse(employeeReqBean.getEmployee().getDol()));     
        Date sDate = sdf.parse(doj);
        Date eDate = sdf.parse(dol);
        long dateDiff = eDate.getDate() - sDate.getDate();
        if(sDate.getDate() > eDate.getDate()) {
            errors.reject("startDate", "Start Date should be less than End Date");
        }
        if (dateDiff > 90 ) {
            errors.reject(" End Date and Start Date difference should not be more than 90 Days ");
        }
        if ((sDate.getDate() == new Date().getDate()) && 
                (eDate.getDate() == new Date().getDate())) {
            errors.reject(" Start Date and End Date should not be current Date ");
        }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error(" error occured validate in EmployeeValidator  " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return EmployeeReqBean.class.equals(clazz);
    }
}
```

In My service class

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/employeeData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ByEmployeeResBean getByEmployeeDetails(@RequestBody String filter) 
        throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        /*
         * Object Mapper for set into EmployeeReqBean
        */
}
```

How use @Valid or @Validate to validate doj and dol coming from the UI in service?

Comment: Please format your question. If you have code to show, post it directly here (formatted), don't post images of code.

Comment: please add code instead of image. It's too small to understand

Comment: Source code is formatted and added.